# Convert data.frame that is a list to data.frame that is intact but characters

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data.frame that is comprised of rows that are each URLs but format of it when I run "typeof" is a list.  This creates some issues when I try to bind it to other data.frames that are character or numeric formats.  I'm trying to convert this data.frame which shows a list with factor levels for each row into a standard data.frame that has each URL intact occupying each row (length unchanged).

I've tried the following:

test <- as.character(web3) - **This leaves me with a vector that is just numbers and no longer resembles anything I started with**

test <- lapply(web3, data.frame, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
test2 <- rbind.fill(test)

Here is a dput of a portion of it:

```
structure(c(35L, 35L, 34L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L), .Label = c("/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911016022379/0001179110-16-022379-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911016028590/0001179110-16-028590-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911016028764/0001179110-16-028764-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911016028975/0001179110-16-028975-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911016029122/0001179110-16-029122-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911016030044/0001179110-16-030044-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911016031144/0001179110-16-031144-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911016032519/0001179110-16-032519-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017003489/0001179110-17-003489-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017009339/0001179110-17-009339-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017009836/0001179110-17-009836-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017011451/0001179110-17-011451-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017011684/0001179110-17-011684-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017011782/0001179110-17-011782-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017013512/0001179110-17-013512-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017013668/0001179110-17-013668-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017013817/0001179110-17-013817-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017014024/0001179110-17-014024-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017014676/0001179110-17-014676-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017015379/0001179110-17-015379-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911018004779/0001179110-18-004779-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911018008826/0001179110-18-008826-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911018009648/0001179110-18-009648-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911018009739/0001179110-18-009739-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911018011490/0001179110-18-011490-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911019004050/0001179110-19-004050-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911019004286/0001179110-19-004286-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911019004323/0001179110-19-004323-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911019005598/0001179110-19-005598-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911019007384/0001179110-19-007384-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911019012669/0001179110-19-012669-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911019013159/0001179110-19-013159-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911020000425/0001179110-20-000425-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911020004224/0001179110-20-004224-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911020004802/0001179110-20-004802-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000120919115082536/0001209191-15-082536-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000120919115083517/0001209191-15-083517-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000120919116095084/0001209191-16-095084-index.htm", 
"/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001015739", "/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001218981&owner=include", 
"/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001326732", "/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcurrent", 
"/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getissuer&CIK=0001015739", "/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getissuer&CIK=0001326732", 
"/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getowner&CIK=0001218981&sortid=filings-ASC", 
"/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getowner&CIK=0001218981&sortid=ownership-data-ASC", 
"/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getowner&CIK=0001218981&sortid=period-of-report-ASC", 
"/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getowner&CIK=0001218981&sortid=type-of-owner-ASC", 
"/edgar/searchedgar/webusers.htm", "/index.htm", "javascript:history.back()"
), class = "factor")
```

## Double-check dput:

```
structure(list(web = structure(c(35L, 35L, 34L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 30L, 29L, 27L, 28L, 27L, 26L, 
26L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
21L, 20L, 20L, 19L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 
9L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 38L, 
38L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 36L, 36L), .Label = c("/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911016022379/0001179110-16-022379-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911016028590/0001179110-16-028590-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911016028764/0001179110-16-028764-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911016028975/0001179110-16-028975-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911016029122/0001179110-16-029122-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911016030044/0001179110-16-030044-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911016031144/0001179110-16-031144-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911016032519/0001179110-16-032519-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017003489/0001179110-17-003489-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017009339/0001179110-17-009339-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017009836/0001179110-17-009836-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017011451/0001179110-17-011451-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017011684/0001179110-17-011684-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017011782/0001179110-17-011782-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017013512/0001179110-17-013512-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017013668/0001179110-17-013668-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017013817/0001179110-17-013817-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017014024/0001179110-17-014024-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017014676/0001179110-17-014676-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911017015379/0001179110-17-015379-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911018004779/0001179110-18-004779-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911018008826/0001179110-18-008826-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911018009648/0001179110-18-009648-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911018009739/0001179110-18-009739-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911018011490/0001179110-18-011490-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911019004050/0001179110-19-004050-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911019004286/0001179110-19-004286-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911019004323/0001179110-19-004323-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911019005598/0001179110-19-005598-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911019007384/0001179110-19-007384-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911019012669/0001179110-19-012669-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911019013159/0001179110-19-013159-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911020000425/0001179110-20-000425-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911020004224/0001179110-20-004224-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911020004802/0001179110-20-004802-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000120919115082536/0001209191-15-082536-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000120919115083517/0001209191-15-083517-index.htm", 
"/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000120919116095084/0001209191-16-095084-index.htm", 
"/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001015739", "/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001218981&owner=include", 
"/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001326732", "/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcurrent", 
"/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getissuer&CIK=0001015739", "/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getissuer&CIK=0001326732", 
"/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getowner&CIK=0001218981&sortid=filings-ASC", 
"/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getowner&CIK=0001218981&sortid=ownership-data-ASC", 
"/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getowner&CIK=0001218981&sortid=period-of-report-ASC", 
"/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getowner&CIK=0001218981&sortid=type-of-owner-ASC", 
"/edgar/searchedgar/webusers.htm", "/index.htm", "javascript:history.back()"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -80L), class = "data.frame")
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: the `str` shows it is a `vector` with class `factor`.  Not clear about what you expect as output

Comment: I'd like the output to no longer be a factor but continue to have the same text

Comment: In that case it would be `as.character(vec1)` or `as.character(test)` if the dput iis from `test`

Comment: This is the output with as.character(test): "c(35, 35, 34, 33, 33, 33, 32, 32, 32, 32, 31, 31, 31, 30, 29, 27, 28, 27, 26, 26, 25, 24, 24, 24, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 22, 22, 22, 21, 20, 20, 19, 19, 18, 18, 18, 17, 17, 17, 16, 16, 16, 15, 15, 15, 14, 14, 13, 13, 13, 12, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 38, 38, 37, 37, 37, 36, 36)"

Comment: I am not able to reproduce that.  I get `as.character(test)#
 [1] "/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911020004802/0001179110-20-004802-index.htm"
 [2] "/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911020004802/0001179110-20-004802-index.htm"...` from your dput

Comment: Strange, thanks for looking at that.  Odd that I'm seeing something different.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: can you check whether you used the same `dput` and is testing on that same data

Comment: is it test2 or test, the new dput

Comment: Now, it is a data.frame with a column named 'web' `as.character(test2$web)#[1] "/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911020004802/0001179110-20-004802-index.htm"
 [2] "/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911020004802/0001179110-20-004802-index.htm"
 [3] "/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911020004224/0001179110-20-004224-index.htm"
 [4] "/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911020000425/0001179110-20-000425-index.htm"
 [5] "/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911020000425/0001179110-20-000425-index.htm"...
` gives a vector

Comment: test is the data frame I'm referencing.  What i'm trying to do is keep the portion of the URL contained and then paste the rest of the web address to get a finalized web address. Again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need to convert the column to `character`, just extract the column and use `as.character`

```
test2$web <- as.character(test2$web)
```

-checking the structure

```
str(test2)
#'data.frame':  80 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ web: chr  "/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911020004802/0001179110-20-004802-index.htm" "/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911020004802/0001179110-20-004802-index.htm" "/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911020004224/0001179110-20-004224-index.htm" "/Archives/edgar/data/0001218981/000117911020000425/0001179110-20-000425-index.htm" ...
```